Run an app without sudo password on MacOS for hidapitester (HID Device Interface)
I have a script that calls hidapitester binary. But I have to run this script with sudo privileges. If it's not called with sudo then it throws an error: Error: could not open device.
Instead of always typing my sudo password when calling this script, is there any way to call this without asking sudo password? Or always-run with root privileges without sudo?

How do you run this script? If it’s by hand, try sudo -s to get a root shell. As you’ve asked several questions this may go off in a direction that’s less helpful, so please edit to ask one clear question if this should get closed. If you search here for the term sudoers that might be the best avenue if you want that script to be always root and not have a root shell. It depends on what you’re doing here long term.

@bmike We have several of those

You found a great one, with a terse Lri answer.

Thanks. I have already that line in visudo file but it doesn't work. That's why I wanted to ask another question here. I thought I was because of maybe we should do additional stuff to make HID Device Interface in macOS.
